# Confusion on Sobel mask

Tags: matlab, opencv

What is the exact mask for Sobel (Gx and Gy)? What I saw is there are two types on how people wrote it such as below,

**Style 1**

```
Gx = [-1 -2 -1
        0 0 0
        1 2 1]

Gy = [-1 0 1
      -2 0 2
      -1 0 1]
```

**Style 2**

```
Gx = [-1 0 1
      -2 0 2
      -1 0 1]

Gy = [-1 -2 -1
        0 0 0
        1 2 1]
```

**Edited**

@Aurelis

In Matlab --> (row x col)

In OpenCV --> (col x row)

However, the diagram below is correct for both

```
-->column
^
|row
|
```

Probably in Matlab will output Gx == horizontal edge, Gy == vertical edge if Style 1 is used and Gx == horizontal edge, Gy ==vertical edge if Style 2 is used. Both will produce same output (internal operation might be different due to the col-row major order).

@Abhishek You are using style 1 to compute the horizontal and vertical edge? and Gx correspond to horizontal edge while Gy correspond to vertical edge?
Does that mean style 2 is complement of that? For eg. computing Gx will gives vertical edge and Gy gives horizontal edge?

Comment: You have switched the orders in your edit to me. MATLAB is the second order; OpenCV the first,

Answer (score 3):

Style 2 is correct. However, using both the styles we will get the same result, as the kernels are convolved with the image

Gx = [-1 -2 -1
        0 0 0  <--- will extract features in Y direction and not in X direction.
        1 2 1]

Gy = [-1 0 1
      -2 0 2  <--- will extract features in X direction and not in Y direction.
      -1 0 1]

This can be verified by using a simple 2-D convolution.

original image: [image: original image]

using Style1,Gx:
[image]

using style1, Gy:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using mathematical notation, the proper mask is Style 2 (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator)).

Your confusion may be arising from the difference between matrices in MATLAB and OpenCV. MATLAB matrices are specified in column-major order, while OpenCV matrices are specified in row-major order.

Style 1 is representing the Sobel mask in a column-major fashion, and Style 2 represents the same mask in row-major order.

Comment: I don't really understand your edits. Perhaps [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) might be helpful.